# How to update phalcon's version on mac os?

Tags: macos, phalcon

Five days ago, Phalcon release it's new version to 3.0 . But my version was still 2.0.13. In Phalcon's doc site, the installation on mac was
`brew install php56-phalcon`

I've checked that phalcon version on homebrew's site was 2.0.13 too :(
So anyone who knows how to update phalcon to the latest version on mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to download appropriate file from https://github.com/majksner/php-phalcon-mamp (based on php version you have) and put it in your php extensions folder. 
If you're gonna contribute or debug phalcon code you should compile it from source available here:
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon

Answer (score 0):

You just can try to compile it from sources. 
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon#linuxunixmac